# DB Design: how to indicate if a column data is public or private

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I'm designing a database and I have a question about how to make private some user data.

I have a user table, with name, city, birthday, biography, etc. And the user can make some data private (*other users can see that data*).

First, I thought to add columns to the table to indicate if a column is private or not. For example:

```
User
-------

user_id  | name | city | cityIsPrivate | birthday | birthdayIsPrivate
---------+------+------+---------------+----------+------------------
```

Or, another approach is to add a varchar column to indicate which columns are private:

```
User
-------

user_id  | name | city | birthday | privateColumns
---------+------+------+----------+---------------
```

And this privateColumns will have this: `"city:NO; birthday:YES"`.

The user table will only have three columns that can be private or public. I will only have to add three columns more to the table.

**Any advice?**

Comment: Create an extra table PublicFields with `user_id` and field (varchar). `FK` with `user_id`. This way u can easily extends the amount of fields without extra coding afterwards

Comment: I like the approach @DarkBee proposes. The thought of having to parse that privateColumns field seems less than ideal. Another table is in order!

Comment: @DarkBee Thanks for your comment. And, what do I have to store in that other table?, the name of the public column?

Comment: Yes indeed, this way u can query which fields u need to show on the user profile page. Columns not listed in the table are private and not a concern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not move data into a separate table if you are going to have to join to it every time you query the main table.

Boolean (or equivalent) columns to indicate privacy for every column on which a privacy setting can be applied:

1. is very simple to add.
2. takes up practically no space.
3. is much quicker to query.
4. shows that the privacy settings are an intrinsic part of the user data.
5. removes unnecessary complexity from the schema.

The facts that these relate to other columns and that they represent a single kind of logical object are just a distraction. Go for simplicity, performance, and logical correctness.

Answer (score 1):

Move the list of you private columns to separate table whith three fields, like:

```
UserId |ColumnName |IsPrivate
-----------------------------
```

Then you can join your queries with that table and get proper result set for each user, and at the same time change the columns of yor user table.

If your User table would not suppose have changes, it is better to move the list of you private columns to separate table with proper structure, like this:

```
UserId |cityIsPrivate |birthdayIsPrivate
----------------------------------------
```

Then you can join your user table with this table in a single query and get result set your need.

But don't make it in the same table. The first approach brings redundancy to your database structure. In your second case you would not be able to make SELECT queries by IsPrivate criterias.

Comment: If you have ten columns to check for privacy settings, does this first method not lead to joining to that separate three column table ten times? This seems little different to an entity-attribute-value schema, which is notoriously hard to query and very cumbersome in practice

Comment: @DavidAldridge Yes, the first way is a hard approach. But it gives a big advantage - a structure independance. For some solutions it is much required. And we can play with PIVOT and UNPIVOT to simplify the work with the results. If we can allow and use consumer side join logic, then we can return two tables and LINQ them to the result collection easily, so no ten joins would be needed. But as your see in answer, recommend the second approach to go, because it is easier.

Comment: I really don't get the advantage of separating the data into two tables. More constraints, more tables, more complex queries with extra joins, higher i/o, higher memory usage, less effective caching ... whatever the benefits, which are not clear to me anyway, they do not seem to make up for the disadvantages. All that aside, use of the two data sets is so tightly coupled that separating them doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @DavidAldridge It is the matter of harbit. As for me, it is more comfortable to work with two separate objects. I know that 1 table is the information about user, another is its access policy. Not a single, where I have to seek what is info and what is the access. And what if I'm a consumer of the database, and see this structure for the first time? In my case if I make a model on the client - it is quite easy. Two classes linked to tables. In your case it can be two classes linked to on table with a select. The client logic becomes more complicated. Each approach has it's bad and good sides.

Comment: @DavidAldridge As for my habit, it is better to have a logic split of data, even with the cost of extra  joins, higher i/o, higher memory usage (I don't this it would have much great effect with proper indexes).

Comment: It sounds like your approach is from the application side, but even with my Rails hat on I could provide logical separation through the app's abstraction layer. Sorry, I just don't get the advantages, and I see too many disadvantages.

Comment: @DavidAldridge What if we decide to add another feature to each column? IsVisibleToAdminOnly for example. And add IsEnabledForGuests then? So each time we have to add new columns to the main table? As a result - we have a huge table with many mixed columns, which is hard to maintaine. Each table has to cover it's funtional purpose.

Comment: @DavidAldridge What is the sence to make abstraction level on application side if you could make a proper structure on DB level? I don't think that joins of two tables would create some difficulties for the developers. I think that making data structure split makes it readable and maintainable, and it worth of increasing the query execution time on 0,001 milliseconds

Answer (score 1):

You can have a separate table (UserPrivateFields, for example) listing user ID's along with fields they have elected to make private, like so:

```
UserID | PrivateField
-------+-------------
1      | Name
1      | City
2      | Birthday
```

When you're running the procedure grabbing the user info to be pulled by the person requesting the info, you can then build a query like this (assume the desired user's UserID is passed into the proc):

```
CREATE TABLE #PublicUserFields (Publicfield varchar(50))
INSERT INTO #PublicUserFields (Publicfield)
SELECT Publicfield
FROM userPublicfields
WHERE userid = @userid

Declare @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT '
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #PublicUserFields)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Publicfield VARCHAR(50) = 
        (SELECT TOP 1 Publicfield FROM #PublicUserFields)
    SET @sql = @SQL + @Publicfield
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #PublicUSERFIELDS) > 1
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = @SQL + ', '
    END

    DELETE FROM #PublicUserFields 
    WHERE Publicfield = @Publicfield
END

SET @SQL = @SQL + ' FROM MainTable WHERE userID = @userID'

EXEC(@SQL)
```

The reason I'm bothering with dynamic SQL is that the names of your public fields can't be joined directly to the column *names* of the main table with this setup - they can only be selected or joined to other records with the same string value. You could maybe get around this by joining to sys.columns and doing interesting things with the object_id of the columns, but that doesn't seem much easier than this appraoch.

This makes sense IF the users can all dynamically set which fields they want to be viewable by other people. If the private fields are known and static, you may just want to separate the two categories and tighten down the permissions on read-access on the private table.

Comment: If you compare the code required to make this separate table work with the code required to mkae attributes on the main table work, is the simplicity of the latter not an argument for avoiding the separate table?